# On Hiring an SEO, what do I need to look for?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, website-design

I am a self employed carpenter with my own website, [housemastersllc.com](https://housemastersllc.com/), I built using GoDaddy. It was cheap, fairly easy to do, it got my content out there that I wanted to show. I do understand, it is what I think I need out there, but it is a start.  I am a one man show looking to expand by generating more leads, to make it possible to hire help.

I have had it for about a year now, some traffic goes there, got a few leads from it, secured the jobs, etc.

I did a Google search for "carpenters near me", and got crickets.... I presume a SEO specialist would correct this. FWIW, when I search for [housemastersllc.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=housemasters%20llc&oq=&aqs=chrome.0.35i39i362l8.1438j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), it shows the website and my FB page, and a Houzz thing. So it is there. That was the biggest trouble I had getting Google to accept it as a company to show *any* search result.
All this said, how do I find the right SEO for my business, will any SEO company work? Is it better to get somebody local? I truly have no idea where to begin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your website can most definitely use [some optimization](https://developers.google.com/search), but *don't expect miracles* from this. A website alone, even an optimized one, doesn't drive all that many customers to your business.

It's like in the real world: The more people talk about your business, the more customers you get. *Word of mouth.* The same is true for the internet: If you're mentioned in many places on the internet, and those people point to your website, the more traffic your site will get. If Google sees that your site is talked about it will be ranked higher.

Examples:

- You build a nice stair for a customer and they put it on their facebook page.
- An influencer asks you to build them a studio desk, and posts it on tiktok.
- You film your work, and put it on YouTube. You'd be surprised how many people find that fascinating and people can see how you work.
- You send a press release, about something special regarding your business, to carpentry websites and some of them actually publish something about it.
- Etc.

My point is that if an SEO only works on your website, and does an excellent job, it will only get you so far. It's the things that happen around the website that are important.

I even think that you can probably do some mundane SEO work yourself, simply by reading [the relevant Google pages](https://developers.google.com/search). Concentrate first on putting the **key words** correctly into your website. You have some:

> Off I-5 Exit 260, Bellingham WA 98226 Carpentry finish trim interior
> trim stairs stair work door trim door install cabinet installation
> consultation

but they're not where search engines expect them, and they're all bunched together. Should the search engine read: "door install", or: "install cabinet"? What does "interior trim stairs" accomplish? Clearly that doesn't work.

You can try the [Google PageSpeed Insight](https://pagespeed.web.dev/) to get some detailed technical advice on *web page* optimization. It's free!

You can also spend money on advertising on Google, that's what Google would like you to do, but I would be very careful with this. The [ROI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_on_investment) is probably pretty bad.

Comment: Pretty sad they closed the question. I gave background on what I have done so far. I do not know what to do next to put it simply other than perhaps going to an SEO, and that was the question. I am surprised it was closed for lack of focus.. That is what I am trying to accomplish.... focus by asking a question....

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it has helped. I know it won't do it all, but it can be a start.